# can anyone suggest me how can i handle thousands of color?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have 3000 color and i want to use these color with color swatches and i uploaded all color in color attribute option. but the site is being very slow and sometimes crashed. can anyone suggest me how can i handle thousands of color.

Comment: At what time is the site slow? When a user navigates the front-end of the site? When you add additional color options to the attribute? When you add new products and choose the simple products? I have a site with 4200+ color options and haven't seen any issues, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I suggest you override the ConfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Super/Collection.php

and try to improve perform the loop (~ line 127)

```
$result = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
            foreach ($result as $data)
```

....

I changed to this

```
$thisClass = $this;
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk(
    $select,
    array(function($args) use (&$thisClass){
        $data = $args['row'];
        $item = $thisClass->getItemById($data['product_super_attribute_id']);
        if (!is_array($labels = $item->getOptionLabels())) {
            $labels = array();
        }
        $labels[$data['option_id']][$data['store_id']] = $data['label'];
        $item->setOptionLabels($labels);
    })
);
```

For me, this does not solve the problem. But to some of friends of mine worked

I had to make a lot of changes in how it (swatches module) works to improve the performance.

Comment: can you please share what changes you made in swatches module. - The above solutions isn't working for me either. I have magento 1.9.2 with one configurable product which has almost 1500 associated simple products